# How to swap using substitution regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a data like

```
3:12:19 [Sam Peters] user at X
11:1:17 [Roger Fernandes] user at Y
10:9:25 [Harry Dsouza] user at Z
```

I want my output to be

```
 [Peters.S] user at X 3:12:19
 [Fernandes.R] user at Y 11:1:17
 [Dsouza.H] user at Z 10:9:25
```

My code is not working. This is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/
use warnings;
use strict;

my $log = "3:12:19 [Sam Peters] user at X \n11:1:17 [Roger Fernandes] user at Y \n10:9:25 [Harry Dsouza] user at Z \n";
print "$log \n";
$log =~ s/ ^
        (.*)     #First group time
        \s                                 #whitespace
        \[                                  #start bracket
           (\w)\s(\w+)                            #name in square barckets
        \]                                  #end brackets
        \s
        (.*)                                #everything else
       $/\[$3\.$2\] $4 $1/gxi;

print "$log \n";
```

I am just a beginner at Perl.I am getting the output same as the input, no change.

Comment: Instead of changing your original regex, it would've been better to just edit your post showing the changes you made (your second attempt) as a whole new set of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple code example, You could read each line of your data and use this regex on each line:

```
$line =~ s/(.*) \[(\w)(\w+) (\w+)\] user at (\w+)/\[$4\.$2\] user at $5 $1/;
```

Substitution regex example on this [link](https://regex101.com/r/ZjW6IU/1) with the above data.

Comment: Can you please also rectify me whats wrong in my code, will hlp me to learn better

Answer (score 1):

`(\w)\s(\w+)` will never match your 'name' data. `(\w)\w+\s(\w+)` works (provided there are no middle names, initials and no endings like 'Jr.' or 'III').

Your capture of the 'time' field works, but could be more safely written as `(\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?)`

`$/\[$3\.$2\] $4 $1/gxi;`

No need to escape the '[  ]' brackets above (every thing in the replacement side of the substitution is treated as an ordinary double quoted string). The `i` modifier isn't necessary here (no case items in the string. None of the  matches needs to identify an upper/lower case letter). And you need the `m` modifier so that `^ and $` match at the beginning and ending of the line (*not* the begin and end of the *string*) (Your `$log` variable is one string with 3 *lines*).

With these changes, the substitution expression might be written:

```
 $log =~ s/^
            (\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?) # capture 'time' stamp
            \s                  # space
            \[                  # opening bracket
               (\w)\w+\s(\w+)   # capture first initial and last name
            \]                  # close bracket
            (.+)$               # remaining to end of 'line'
            /[$3.$2]$4$1/mgx;
```

Comment: Thanks...it is helpful